# I'm querying a schema that is identical across 2 xml files except for the highest level

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

How do I write a single xquery within tsql to access the XML below? As you can see one has, 
FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn

```
-<FIXML 
-<Batch>
 -<AllocInstrctn ID="444xxx" TransTyp="0" Typ="1" ID2="2088767" LinkID="4459475"
```

the other, FIXML/AllocInstrctn

```
<FIXML 
<AllocInstrctn ID="444xxx" TransTyp="0" Typ="1" ID2="2088767" LinkID="4459475"
```

Otherwise the Nodes are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to do this:

1. Use the **`descendant-or-self` axis step**, abbreviated `//`:

   ```
   /FIXML//AllocInstrctn
   ```

   Advantage: Short and easy to read, disadvantage: also matches `/FIXML/foo/bar/AllocInstrctn` etc.
2. Use a **sequence** in the middle of the XPath expression as axis step:

   ```
   /FIXML/(Batch, .)/AllocInstrctn
   ```

   Advantage: More specific on what to match.

   MS SQL Server does not support sequences in the middle of an expression, so you will have to apply a similar pattern to the XPath 1.0 version with union and repeat the whole path from the beginning: `/FIXML/Batch, /FIXML)/AllocInstrctn` (thanks to @MikaelEriksson for pointing this out).
3. Especially if bound to XPath 1.0, which does not support solution 2, use the **union operator**:

   ```
   (/FIXML/Batch | /FIXML)/AllocInstrctn
   ```

   Disadvantage: Cannot be used in the middle of an XPath expression as an axis step, thus you have to repeat the full path from the root (cannot use something like `/FIXML/(Batch | .)/AllocInstrctn

For this small number of alternatives (namely: two) I'd go for the second solution. If you're bound to XPath 1.0, solution one might be a viable way to go for although less specific, as solution 3 can result in very long XPath expressions for more complicated documents.

Comment: A "more specific" version that works in SQL Server would be `(/FIXML/Batch, /FIXML)/AllocInstrctn`. Union is not supported.

Comment: SQL Server does not support version 2 (which is mainly the same like your's, but with intermediate sequence generation)?

Comment: No, strangely enough number 2 is not supported either. It works if the sequence is first in the expression. Not in the middle.

Comment: So SQL Server has the same restrictions like XPath 1.0 with the union operator. SQL Server is also great for a surprise on missing XQuery features...